# Is it possible to exclude unsigned-in user if URL contains particular parameter when using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There's URL like this

```
example.com/users/1376
```

Anyone can see this page even if the user is not signed-in.

There's also URL like this

```
example.com/users/1376?mode=1
```

Only signed-in user can see this page, otherwise the user will be redirected to sign-in page(new_users_session_path)

Could it be something like this?

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:show(params[:mode]=1)]
```

If not, please show me how to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rails 3.2

`before_filter :redirect_user, :only => :show`

For rails 4

`before_action :redirect_user, :only => :show`

```
def redirect_user          
 if params[:mode] == 1 && current_user      
  redirect_to user_path(id: params[:id], mode: 1) #example.com/users/1376?mode=1
 elsif !current_user && params[:mode].blank?
   redirect_to user_path(id: params[:id]) 
 else  
  redirect_to new_users_session_path
 end     
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Rails 3.2  So is it impossible to do this considering params?

Comment: sorry i can not get your question you can check the params in controller as i did `params[:mode] == 1`

Comment: Sorry about that! I got it now. the block was for both Rails3 and 4. That makes sense now. Thanks:)

Comment: Is it possible to hide `?mode=1` when googlerobot is accessing to the page? I want to show `example.com/users/1376` instead. I think I have to do something in application_helper

Answer (score 2):

Have the before_filter (before_action for rails 4) call a method which renders or redirects if the action should not be run.

```
before_filter :test_for_mode, :only => :show

...

private
  def test_for_mode
    if (params[:mode] == '1') && !user_signed_in?
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
```

Comment: Whoops, code redirects if user is signed in. It should be negated. I'll correct it.

Comment: Is it possible to hide `?mode=1` when googlerobot is accessing to the page? I want to show `example.com/users/1376` instead. I think I have to do something in application_helper

Comment: Yeah, if the User-Agent is a bot, you could leave off the '?mode=1' when rendering the page. Of course, this lets people bypass the login requirement if they know to set the User-Agent appropriately.